# excel visual basic command button link

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I have created a command button from inside the code using this:

```
Public Sub createForm(label As String)
Dim control As control
Dim controlbutton As CommandButton

'set control for the first label on the page
Set control = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Text", True)
With control
    .Caption = label
    .Left = 25
    .Top = 10
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 200
    .Visible = True
End With

'set control for the enter button
Set controlbutton = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Enter", True)
With controlbutton
    .Caption = "Enter"
    .Name = "Enter"
    .Left = 45
    .Top = 80
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
End With

'set control for the cancel button
Set controlbutton = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CancelButton", True)
    With controlbutton
        .Caption = "Cancel"
        .Left = 105
        .Top = 80
        .Height = 30
        .Width = 50
        .Visible = True
    End With


    'UserForm1.Controls.Add "Forms.TextBox.1", "Name1", True
    'UserForm1!Name1.Text = "Hi"
End Sub
```

But i want to be able to do something when the button is clicked. i did this:

```
Sub CancelButton_Click()

    UserForm1.Name = "Closed"

End Sub
```

this did not work as the event was never run.
all of this is running inside the form code. i have got initialize etc but this is a custom function. it creates and shows the buttons but just will not let me run an event when its clicked.

What i am after is when the cancel button is clicked it closes the form.

Comment: replace that with: Unload Me

Comment: the event isnt firing so i cant do that. i dont understand why it isnt firing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you need to put your code inside the `UserForm`. Then you need to add a class that will handle all the button click event. If you search for "vba userform add controls runtime" you'll find some good answers, even some here on SO. Here's what you do for your particular situation:

First in the VBE, insert a new `Class module` and call it "**clsButton**." Inside this module you'll add this code:

```
Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton
Private Sub btn_Click()
If btn.Caption = "Cancel" Then
    MsgBox "Cancel"
ElseIf btn.Caption = "Enter" Then
    MsgBox "Enter"
End If
End Sub
```

The WithEvents keyword declares a `btn` object that triggers events when clicked. You can use the `Caption` property, as above, or perhaps the `Tag` property to distinguish which button actually triggered the event.

Now you need to add your modified code to the UserForm:

```
Public cButton As clsButton
Public coll As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim controlbutton As CommandButton
Set controlbutton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Enter", True)
With controlbutton
    .Caption = "Enter"
    .Name = "Enter"
    .Left = 45
    .Top = 80
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
    Set cButton = New clsButton
    Set cButton.btn = controlbutton
    coll.Add cButton
End With

Set controlbutton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CancelButton", True)
With controlbutton
    .Caption = "Cancel"
    .Left = 105
    .Top = 80
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
    Set cButton = New clsButton
    Set cButton.btn = controlbutton
    coll.Add cButton
End With
End Sub
```

We declare two public variables, one to hold an instance of the class we just created, and a collection to hold the class instances for the life of the userform. In the UserForm_Activate event we instantiate a new instance of the class for each button and add it to the collection.

Then just run the form and click the buttons.

EDIT: Here's a response to your request to add a `ComboBox` to the mix. This code adds a ComboBox to `clsButton` and changes the `Enter` button to display the current value of the ComboBox:

```
Public WithEvents btn As msforms.CommandButton
Public cbo As msforms.ComboBox

Private Sub btn_Click()
If btn.Caption = "Cancel" Then
    MsgBox "Cancel"
ElseIf btn.Caption = "Enter" Then
    MsgBox cbo.Value
End If
End Sub
```

The form code is altered to create the ComboBox, fill it with some values, and set the selection to the its item. Then when the `Enter` button is created the `cbo` property is set for its class instance. The Cancel button code is unchanged:

```
Public cButton As clsButton
Public coll As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim controlButton As msforms.CommandButton
Dim controlCombo As msforms.ComboBox
Dim i As Long

Set controlCombo = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Combo", True)
With controlCombo
    For i = 1 To 10
        .AddItem i
    Next i
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

Set controlButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Enter", True)
With controlButton
    .Caption = "Enter"
    .Name = "Enter"
    .Left = 45
    .Top = 80
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
    Set cButton = New clsButton
    Set cButton.btn = controlButton
    Set cButton.cbo = controlCombo
    coll.Add cButton
End With

Set controlButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "CancelButton", True)
With controlButton
    .Caption = "Cancel"
    .Left = 105
    .Top = 80
    .Height = 30
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
    Set cButton = New clsButton
    Set cButton.btn = controlButton
    coll.Add cButton
End With
End Sub
```

So, to summarize, we've added a ComboBox to the class, and added it the the Enter button's class instance, so that btn can "talk" to it.

Comment: this has worked very well! thank you for your help you have solved one of my major headaches!

Comment: thanks for the code, i added a combo box into the mix, how would i read it through your code when the button is pressed, ive googled it and tried but failed to do it.

I know it would be put in the if statement but im not sure on how to get the combobox values.

Thanks in advance